# How to include a commit in a tag after the tag was already created

Tags: git, github, git-tag

I had tagged my branch for release and then another commit was made that needs to be included in the tag.

How can I do that ? What are the steps?

Can someone explain please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just move the tag to the new commit.
steps:

- delete the tag
- checkout at new commit
- apply the tag

don't forget to push to update the remote